# Angular JS - Not able to hit the controller from my routing code

Tags: angularjs

For some reason , I am not able to hit the controller post my routing logic is called. Though I have envent handlers to track the routing, I dont see any message being printed in the console logs. Please can you guide me here?

**ROUTING**

```
angular
    .module('icebergApp')
    .config(setupRouting);

setupRouting.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function setupRouting($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/iceberg-ui");
    $stateProvider
        .state('iceberg.reconlist', {
            url: "/iceberg-ui",
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/reconlist/reconlist.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconListController as vm'
        })


}
}());

angular.module('app').run(setupRoutingEventListeners);

setupRouting.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function setupRoutingEventListeners($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeStart to '+toState.name+'- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : \n',toState, toParams);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.log('$stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition.');
        console.log(arguments);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeSuccess to '+toState.name+'- fired once the state transition is complete.');
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading',function(event, viewConfig){
        console.log('$viewContentLoading - view begins loading - dom not rendered',viewConfig);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateNotFound '+unfoundState.to+'  - fired when a state cannot be found by its name.');
        console.log(unfoundState, fromState, fromParams);
    });
   }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = angular.module('iceberg.reconlist');
    myApp.controller('ReconListController', ReconListController);

    ReconListController.$inject = ['ReconListService'];

    function ReconListController(ReconListService) {
        var vm = this;
}
}());
```

**MODULE**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('icebergApp', [
               'ui.router',
        'iceberg.reconlist'
    ]);

    angular.module('iceberg.reconlist', [
    ]);    
}());
```

Comment: Did you check for errors?

Comment: I am not getting errors, and that is why I added above event listeners. What i notice is none of the even listeners are getting called, I don't see any fromState or toState when I put my debugger on to it during the breakpoint.

Comment: Have you imported the controller into your routing file?

Comment: I have set the dependency in the modules, iceberg.reconlist module is passed to icebergApp module. I guess that should be enough. What do you mean by importing controller into routing file (angular 1.5), can you please elaborate?

Comment: your routing code is in a module called `app`, but it doesn't seem to have any reference to `icebergApp` or visa versa.

Comment: Sorry, its a copy paste error, It is icebergApp not App. I have corrected it . In my code it is icebergApp, just to confirm, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Try to access your rout with http://localhost:XXX/#/iceberg-ui But replace localhost first :)

Comment: @Vitaili - even though i call with iceberg-ui as the context in the url as you have suggested, I dont see the start change event getting called. There is nothing printing to the console despite having hooks to print to the console when stage change happens. I using angular-ui-router version 0.2.0 and 1.0.0 , both are not working.

Answer (score 1):

you define module by

`angular.module('icebergApp', []);`

and later you have used

`angular.module('app').run(setupRoutingEventListeners);`

that is the main issue.

Comment: Sorry, its a copy paste error, It is icebergApp not App. I have corrected it . In my code it is icebergApp, just to confirm, but the issue still persists. – alice 48 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    controller: 'ReconListController as vm'
```

to

```
    controller: 'ReconListController'
```

Comment: I don't think that helps. You can use 'Controller as aliasname' with the controller name. I have used it before and that works fine.